# Vox-style dynamic charts in Final Cut Pro X

Tags: after-effects, final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro, motion, motion-graphics

I am wondering how I could replicate *dynamic charts* like those made by Vox in **Final Cut Pro X**.

For instance, like this dynamic graph found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BE-cA4UK07c&t=19s) ("The big lesson from South Korea's coronavirus response"):

[image]

I tried the FCPX Charts from *Pixel Film Studios* add-on library but it is not quite there yet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better served with Motion 5 or similar programs for something like that.

Here is a good example from Ripple Training what might work as starting point for you.